# OS X Lion not available in U.S. Store

Tags: macos, snow-leopard

I recently had my computer brought to the the Genius Bar, and they installed a copy of OS X Snow Leopard onto my computer. However, I was previously running Lion. So I went over to the Mac App Store to try and reinstall Lion, and it keeps telling me that the item I've requested is not available in the U.S. Store. Is there any way I can resolve the issue? I've tried switching stores and had no luck.

Comment: That is strange - I just initiated a download of OSX Lion from my purchases, and in the US Store, and it started without problems. Have you signed out/in, and then used the download link from your purchases?

Comment: I'm going to close this as a duplicate, but if you want to edit in details (like perhaps that your Apple ID already purchased Lion and you are just trying to re-download it), then we should probably undo the duplicate close...

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, Apple no longer sells OS X Lion in the Mac App Store. It's not even available in the US Mac App Store and there is no way that you can get OS X Lion from Apple. You can always ask around for a copy, or torrent it (I **very** well advise against this), but other than that, there's nothing that you can do but to upgrade to OS X Mavericks.

Comment: Actually, this is incorrect. Not only can you still purchase it, OS X Lion is still available in "Purchases".

Comment: @bassplayer7 I'm aware that you can re-download it in "Purchases", but looking around in the Mac App Store, I can't find it, so it's safe to assume that it is no longer available for purchase.

Comment: We already have a thread covering the question whether Lion is or isn't still available for purchase online. (The short answer is you can buy Lion physically only - not anymore online as a download).

Comment: Yes, it isn't exactly in the Mac App Store: http://store.apple.com/us/product/D6106Z/A/os-x-lion. After purchase, you will be sent a redemption code for downloading it in the Mac App Store. @bmike - I think this changed as of Mavericks release, but it is available as a download now at that link.

Comment: @bassplayer7 Woah! That is so cool. I've heard that Apple is distributing more and more content using gift codes. Here they have the web store sell the SKU and you get emailed redemption codes as if a consumer "gifted" the App. Very elegant. Check this link, too - http://store.apple.com/us/help/downloadable_software#MacOSX